# Extract Value from Http response in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, httpresponse

I'm trying to extract the value from the following response:

```
[#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>]:Array
```

I tried doing this:

```
response = notifier.get_response();    #response is[#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>]:Array
resp = response[0]
puts JSON.parse(resp.body)
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
 Failure/Error: puts JSON.parse(resp.body)

 JSON::ParserError:
   785: unexpected token at 'ok'
```

Am I extracting this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not JSON, you get string `ok` in the response, which is not a valid response. You can check it by pringting the body first:

```rb
resp = response[0]
p resp.body # <===
puts JSON.parse(resp.body)
```